# Get information from bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have a jwt after login successfully and want to get data from that token (token has encoded containing information saving with Claims).
Is there a way to get data from bearer token using HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)?
I do not know how to get data from the token recieved. Here is my code.

```
public async Task<TokenResponse> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = await dataContext.Users
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password.Encrypt())
                       ?? throw new BadRequestExceptions("Wrong username or password");

        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName,user.Name),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Upn, user.Username)
        };

        var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenConfig.Key));
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var tokenString = new JwtSecurityToken(tokenConfig.Issuer, tokenConfig.Audience, claims: claims, signingCredentials: signingCredentials);

        tokenResponse = new TokenResponse()
        {
            Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenString)
        };
        return tokenResponse;
    }
```

Comment: if you've done it right, you should already have all information in a ClaimsPrincipal. but since i can't see your code, i can't tell if you did.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I have added comments, can you please check it and tell me what would I do to get data from the token recieved? I'm newbie with asp .net core 

Comment: you've included the code where you create the token. _not where you handle the received token_. the code you provided is, basically, irrelevant. also: i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thanks for you support but my question is how to receive information in that ClaimsPrinciple, that's why I don't have the code `handle the received token` as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get data out of your token (provided you have multiple data to retrieve) is to extend (extension methods) ClaimsPrincipal and then you can call whatever methods you extend within that class from anywhere within your assembly.
Find a sample below:

```
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
{
    public static string GetUsername(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        return user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
    }

    public static int GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        return int.Parse(user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in your controller action, you can call **User.GetUsername()** and **User.GetUserId()**

However, if you only have to retrieve one or two records, then this would suffice:

```
int userId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value)
```

Happy coding!!!

Comment: Many thanks for your guide, I figured out the way to handle my problem. Have a good morning/ afternoon/ night 